# Getting error while testing the source database endpoint using AWS DMS service

Tags: postgresql, aws-dms

I have two EC2 instances running with the same Postgres database server (same versions in both). I'm using AWS DMS service to migrate data from the source to the target database.
While creating the endpoints and testing for the source database, I'm getting the below error (refer to screenshot):-

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failure in resolving database version. The database version is not supported., Application-Detailed-Message: Supported major version numbers range is [9..14]. Source database version number is not supported: 150003 PostgreSQL 15.3 (Ubuntu 15.3-1.pgdg22.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, 64-bit
```

If I test my target endpoint then it is successful.
What could be the issue here? I created both EC2 instances with Postgres setup using my custom AMI only. I can connect to both databases with correct credentials using DBeaver and directly over the terminal of each instance using `psql`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html
Pls refer above link.
Postgres Version above 14.x are not supported by AWS DMS. You will have to downgrade your postgres version to 14.x